# how to reply a file as a stream in hapi js?

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I have an excel file. I want to reply excel file as a stream to the user using hapi JS reply object. I tried like this but it didn't work.

```
let readStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
reply(null,readStream.pipe());
```

Could anyone suggest me an approach to achieve this?

Comment: You want to print excel data ??? I mean you want to display excel data ..

Comment: response need to download as a excel file.no need to print excel.i can directly send file to the user but i am getting the data from database as a stream so that rather than writing to a excel file and then reply back excel file.i want to use streams.

Comment: Checkout my answer ..Let me know if u have any queries....

Comment: I did file reading in stream format and I am able to print stream data in console and at a time file is being downloading is it ok for you??? If it is kk I will update ....

Comment: yes,could you please update

Comment: Check my answer I updated it with streaming...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this code for serving file . If files are static files it prints on browser otherthan static files like pdf,excel,word these files will be downloaded .

```js
'use strict';

const Path = require('path');
const Hapi = require('hapi');
var fs = require('fs');
const server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({
  port: 3000,
  host: 'localhost'
});

server.register(require('inert'), (err) => {

  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/testdoc.docx',
    handler: function(request, reply) {
      var stream = fs.createReadStream('./testdoc.docx');
      stream.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log('loaded part of the file');
        //reply(null,data);
        reply(data);
      });
      stream.on('end', function() {
        console.log('all parts is loaded');
      });

    }
  });

  server.start((err) => {

    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }

    console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
  });
});
```

run the server `node server.js` and in browser run as `http://localhost:3000/testdoc.docx`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the code.this is exactly what  i am using now but i want to send file as a stream because  write and read can happen at a time.once stream completed i can delete the file(currently i am using settimeout with 2mints but thats not a good approach for security)